# Detect if current connection is metered with NetworkManager

Tags: linux, shell, networkmanager

How can I detect whether the current connection is marked as metered on a system with NetworkManager?

This is from a shell script, but I can easily call any C functions via Python.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With the nmcli utility, the necessary steps are:

1. verify NetworkManager is [version 1.0.6+](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/NEWS?h=1.0.6):

   `$ nmcli -v
   nmcli tool, version 1.9.0`
2. check GENERAL.METERED on an interface:

   `$ nmcli -t -f GENERAL.METERED dev show eth1
   GENERAL.METERED:unknown`
3. [values are: `unknown, yes, no, yes (guessed), no (guessed)`](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/nm-dbus-types.html#NMMetered)
4. Forcing the value is done like this:

   `$ nmcli dev modify wlan1 connection.METERED yes
    Connection successfully reapplied to device 'wlan1'
    $ nmcli -t -f GENERAL.METERED dev show wlan1
    GENERAL.METERED:yes`

And, to get a list grouped by device:

```
  $ nmcli -t -f GENERAL.DEVICE,GENERAL.METERED dev show

  GENERAL.DEVICE:wlan1
  GENERAL.METERED:yes

  GENERAL.DEVICE:eth1
  GENERAL.METERED:unknown

  GENERAL.DEVICE:lo
  GENERAL.METERED:unknown
```

Trying to cut this down to info on just the default route would still require [a call to another command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204629/how-do-i-get-the-default-gateway-in-linux-given-the-destination) as NetworkManager doesn't try to distinguish between multiple devices in a connected state:

```
  $ nmcli -t -f GENERAL.DEVICE,GENERAL.METERED dev show `ip route list 0/0 | sed -r 's/.*dev (\S*).*/\1/g'`
```

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way to only show the information for the network the first default route is going over? With many VPNs and otherwise virtual networks, the output of `nmcli -t -f GENERAL.METERED dev show` (without a device) is a mixture of all possible values for me.

Comment: I've added a way to see the device names, but I think you may need to ask `ip route` and ideally `ip monitor` to reliably track the interface of the default route or relevant server then do/redo the nmcli query.

Comment: Thanks! I'll award the bounty in a couple of hours.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364927/networkmanager-set-current-connection-of-device-as-metered, which describes how to set the connection (i.e. SSID) rather than the interface. This makes sense when you may have more than wifi connection, one to a mobile hotspot.

Comment: You can test the output with `[[ "$(nmcli -t -f GENERAL.METERED dev show \`ip route list 0/0 | sed -r 's/.*dev (\S*).*/\1/g'\` | cut -d':' -f2)" == yes* ]]`

Answer (score 13):

You can also get the metered status of the current connection via D-Bus. From a shell, you can use `busctl`:

```
busctl get-property org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.NetworkManager Metered
```

which is only one command, in contrast to the `nmcli` solution, and in other programming languages it can be more efficient to use D-Bus directly instead of having to call `nmcli`.

The result is an enum with the following values  ([documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-dbus-types.html#NMMetered)):

| Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `NM_METERED_UNKNOWN` | 0 | The metered status is unknown |
| `NM_METERED_YES` | 1 | Metered, the value was explicitly configured |
| `NM_METERED_NO` | 2 | Not metered, the value was explicitly configured |
| `NM_METERED_GUESS_YES` | 3 | Metered, the value was guessed |
| `NM_METERED_GUESS_NO` | 4 | Not metered, the value was guessed |

Comment: The result is an enum with the following [values](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-dbus-types.html#NMMetered)

Comment: The output is something like: `u 1` . If you prefer JSON, then pass the `-j` flag, and you will get output like `{ "type": "u", "data": 1 }`

Comment: For future explorers, you can use Gnome's `D-Spy` app to explore and get the service, object, interface, and property names passed to `busctl`. It even tells you the datatype and lets you query the property in real-time. Invaluable!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the solution from lossleader always returns no on my system, while using the metered parameter from the connection works fine:

`` nmcli -f connection.metered connection show `nmcli -t -f GENERAL.CONNECTION --mode tabular device show $DEVICE | head -n1` ``